# how to get the value from select2 and use it for the next select2

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="" class="control-label">Skill</label> <br>
    <select name="skill[]" class="select-skill-only form-control" id="req-skill" multiple="multiple" required>
        @foreach ($skill2 as $skill)

        <option value="{{$skill->skill_id}}">{{$skill->skill_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    <label for="" class="control-label">Skill Priority</label> <br>
    <select name="priority[]" class="select-skill-only form-control" id="req-priority" multiple="multiple" required>
        @foreach ($skill2 as $priorityskill)

        <option value="{{$priorityskill->skill_id}}">{{$priorityskill->skill_name}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: use ajax to load 2second select data

Comment: thanks. But sorry, i am newbie of using ajax script

Comment: then learn ajax

Comment: okay, that's a good solution, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set a listener for change any select and get value it after any change.
for this you give id to selects.
for example :

```
let skills = [];
$('#skill-select').on('change', function(){
   skills = $(this).val();
   $('#priority-select  > option').each(function() {
      if(!skills.includes($(this).val())){
         $(this).prop('disabled', true)
       }
   });

});
```

and use skills selected array everywhere

Comment: i really apreciate this, in my case :

first select (skill)=
-A
-B(selected)
-C(selected)

then, second select (priority skill):
-A (can't be selected because not choosen in first one)
-B (select it and then can't select C)
-C (select it and then can't select B)

Comment: @Divianis select priority can multi select or single?

Comment: skill priority it's single

Comment: @Divianis edit my answer related your comment, Is what you mean?